# Creating array of objects using the properties from source array of objects based on grouping

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
    let sampleData = [
      { values: { val1: 4, val2: 5, val3: 7 } , time: "1571372233234" , sum: 16 },
      { values: { val1: 5, val2: 3, val3: 1 }, time: "1571372233234" , sum: 9},
      { time: "14354545454", sum: 0},
      { time: "14354545454", sum: 0} }
    ];
```

I need to take each key within each object inside array and form an array out of it. Basically grouping based on the key present in all the objects.If the object has no "values" it should return 0 across the val1,val2,val3 Help would be appreciated.

The resultant array of objects should look like:

```
result = [
  { name: 'val1', data: [4, 5, 0, 0] }, 
  { name: 'val2', data: [5, 3, 0, 0] }, 
  { name: 'val3', data: [7, 1, 0, 0] }
]
```

I have tried so far:

```
var result = sampleData.map(value => ({ value: value.values }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. Create an accumulator with each `valx` as key and `{ name: valx, data: [] }` as it's value. Loop through the keys of each `values` and update the accumulator. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the merged object to get the desired output

```js
const sampleData = [
   { values: { val1: 4, val2: 5, val3: 7 } },
   { values: { val1: 5, val2: 3, val3: 1 }},
   { values: { val1: 4, val2: 7, val3: 2 } },
   { values: { val1: 5, val2: 1, val3: 5 } }
];

const merged = sampleData.reduce((acc, { values }) => {
  for (const name in values) {
    acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, data: [] }
    acc[name].data.push(values[name])
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)

console.log(output)
```

**Update:**

If `values` is optional, you could check if `values` is undefined. But, if you need `0` when `values` doesn't exist, then another step is required. First, we need to get all the possible `valx` keys available in the array. Because, if `{ time: "14354545454", sum: 0}` appears in the beginning of the array, there is no way of knowing what possible keys exist in the array. You can do this using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Then loop through the set of keys for every object. If `values` doesn't exists, add a default `0` for the current `valx` key being looped.

```js
let sampleData = [
   { values: { val1: 4, val2: 5, val3: 7 } , time: "1571372233234" , sum: 16 },
   { values: { val1: 5, val2: 3, val3: 1 }, time: "1571372233234" , sum: 9},
   { time: "14354545454", sum: 0},
   { time: "14354545454", sum: 0}
];

const keySet = new Set( sampleData.flatMap(a => Object.keys(a.values || {})) )

const merged = sampleData.reduce((acc, { values = {} }) => {
  keySet.forEach(name => {
    acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, data: [] }
    acc[name].data.push(values[name] || 0)
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Comment: a small edit . I have changed the sampleData array. I am basically trying to prepare the data for the stacked bar graph. in your above answer, how would I handle this;  suppose there is no "values" object it should return 0 across val1,val2,val3 so that while plotting graph it would show as no value for that time interval